# Нужна ли запятая перед и прочее

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "и прочее": Дальше перечисляются и дети, и поклоны родственникам, и прочее, и прочее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересно, что это выражение **весьма популярно в художественных текстах, но оформляется по-разному.** Мне кажется, что нужно учитывать структуру текста. Например, в распространенных предложениях при наличии перечислительной интонации допустима постановка запятой.

Сам же причудливым образом ― но вполне сознательно и с удовольствием ― смешивал звуки, ту же валторну сводил с ситарами, выхватывал дальние обертоны, и прочее, и прочее! (Владимир Орлов. Альтист Данилов).

Конечно, раздражительность эта ненадолго, однако нельзя не считаться с условиями, в которых мы пребываем: нелегкая дорога, которая становится все труднее, неопределенность нашего даже самого ближайшего будущего, беззащитность и прочее, и прочее… (Булат Окуджава).

И, разумеется, шпионаж в пользу Ирукана, Соана, варваров, баронов, Святого Ордена и прочее, и прочее… (Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Трудно быть богом).

Answer (score 5):

Слова и т. д. (и так далее), и т. п. (и тому подобное) не выступают в роли однородных членов предложения, и запятая перед ними не ставится, даже если союз и повторяется перед предшествующими однородными членами: В этот цикл естественных наук входят и биология, и физика, и химия и т. д.; На выставку можно представить и рисунки, и этюды, и наброски и т.д.

См. Справочник по пунктуации. Д.Э. Розенталь.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ.

Comment: "Слова **и т. д.** (и так далее), **и т. п.** (и тому подобное)..." === Но вопрос-то был про "**и прочее**"!

Comment: Но ведь это синонимы.

Answer (score 2):

> Дальше перечисляются и дети, и поклоны родственникам, и прочее, и
>   прочее.

В правилах ничего о ***и прочее*** не нашёл. В Гугл-книгах -- и с запятыми, и без запятых...

**Грамота.ру** рекомендует запятые не ставить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]