# "и пр. и пр." – нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, сокращения

"и пр. и пр." – нужна ли запятая перед вторым "и"?

Comment: Повтор https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416061/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-и-прочее

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Не совсем повтор. Возможно, при сокращенном написании запятые ставятся иначе.

Comment: Спасибо М_Г. Действительно, мой вопрос не был дубликатом. Несокращенный вариант (о кот. уже шла речь) мне не был нужен. И вы правы, написание в сокр. и несокр. виде, как выяснилось, разнится. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Употреблении слов "и прочее и прочее" (в несокращенном варианте) обсуждалось  [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416061/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B5). Повторюсь, Грамота считает, что **запятые не нужны** (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=245917). На мой взгляд, объясняется это тем, что это устойчивое выражение, подобное "и т. д. и т. п.".

Интересно, что для несокращенного варианта в Нацкорпусе можно найти все варианты постановки запятых (а их больше чем три), а вот сокращенный присутстует в основном **без запятых** (сотни вхождений).

Comment: Интересно, откуда Грамота берет свои ответы. Ссылки на действующие правила никогда не даются, как доверять этой информации?  И вообще, какой у этой структуры официальный статус, можно ли на нее ссылаться?

Comment: О статусе здесь: http://gramota.ru/gramota/about/.  Выглядит серьезно. Портал обязуется давать **квалифицированную помощь**. Ну и воообще - на него все ссылаются...

Answer (score 0):

**В сокращенном варианте с повтором это выражение практически не встречается (или встречается очень редко).**

А вот в полном варианте запятые ставятся авторами по своему усмотрению, так как в классических правилах эта тема, вероятно, не рассматривается.

Чаще встречается вариант (1), хотя он не кажется обоснованным, так как конструкция с повтором **должна отделяться запятой** на правах обычных однородных членов, как в варианте (3), или как присоединительная.

Конструкция (2) выглядит как присоединительная, причем в частном случае запятая между одинаковыми словами не ставится, пауза не делается.

Примеры:

(1) Телевизоры, компьютеры, радиотелефоны **и прочее, и прочее** ― всё это плоды цивилизации и к культуре не имеет никакого отношения. [Фазиль Искандер. Курортная идиллия (1999)]

(2) Во-первых, усталость от холостой жизни, от беспорядка в комнатах, от трактирных обедов, от грязи, окурков, разорванного и разрозненного белья, от долгов, от бесцеремонных товарищей, **и прочее и прочее.** [А. И. Куприн. Гранатовый браслет (1911)]

(3) Сам же причудливым образом ― но вполне сознательно и с удовольствием ― смешивал звуки, ту же валторну сводил с ситарами, выхватывал дальние обертоны, **и прочее, и прочее!..** [Владимир Орлов. Альтист Данилов (1980)]

Comment: А как же Розенталь: *При двукратном повторении союза И (если число однородных членов — два) запятая ставится **при наличии обобщающего слова** при однородных членах предложения*?

Comment: И кстати, я не понимаю следующее за этим "однако" (может объясните мне?): ***Однако** при отсутствии указанных условий при однородных членах предложения, образующих тесное смысловое единство, запятая может не ставиться.* Звучит, будто при их отсутствии запятая может как **не** ставиться, так и ставиться, всё как вздумается, правил нету...

Comment: Sharon, прокомментируйте, пожалуйста (заранее спасибо!). И ещё можете объяснить разницу между "и прочее и прочее" и "и прочая и прочая"? Или это на выбор человека просто (старый и современный вариант)? Спасибо!

Comment: Артем, чуть позже, хорошо? А то сейчас никак не получится со временем.

Comment: Да, конечно. :) Простите, что торопил, просто засомневался, дождусь ли я вообще ответа.

Comment: О тесном смысловом единстве. В некоторых случаях два однородных члена, связанные повторяющимися союзами И...И, НИ...НИ, образуют смысловое единство, то есть произносятся в одну фразу без перечислительной интонации и без паузы, запятая на письме отсутствует. Для этого нужны определенные условия: отсутствие обобщающего слова и зависимых слов, а также другие показатели: ассоциативные (часто антонимические) связи, фразеологический характер выражения.

Comment: Вся конструкция в этом случае воспринимается как единое целое с обобщенным или усиленным значением. Например, если выражение «и зимой и летом» означает "всегда", то это обобщение, запятая не ставится. Но в принципе обобщения может и не быть,  например: я беру отпуск и зимой, и летом (обычное перечисление). Таким образом, окончательное решение зависит и от контекста, и от автора тоже (то есть от его желания передать усиленное или обобщенное значение).

Comment: О выражении «и прочая, и прочая» http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/hardwords?layout=item&id=25_369 
   
Это архаическое мн. число ср. рода. Исторически в русском (и в др.  языках) мн. число ср. рода в И.п. совпадало внешне с ед. числом  ж. рода. Так что именно ср. род был в выражениях "и прочая, и прочая, и прочая. Для многих языков характерно обобщение абстрактных понятий через ср. род прилагательного. Только в русском возобладало употребление ед. числа. Так что если перевести  выражение "и прочая, и прочая, " на современный русский язык, то будет "и прочее, и прочее, и прочее".

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что это одно и то же и что "прочая" — мн. ч. ср. рода. Меня просто интересует, какое сейчас предпочтительно к использованию. Спасибо за комментарии! Получается, отсутствие обобщающего слова или зависимых слов — ***недостаточное условие*** для того, чтобы не ставить запятую?

Comment: Да, недостаточное. Кстати, в ПАС сначала называется отсутствие обобщающих и зависимых слов, а затем говорится о третьем факторе - смысловом единстве. Смысловое единство подробнее разбирается у Розенталя, ну а по реальной практике письма можно видеть наличие вариантов даже среди  устойчивых сочетаний, которые в определенных условиях они пишутся с перечислением.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!)